# get and set in mongoose schema not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

i'm new to mongoose and mongoldb, in my mongoldb, i'm having the schema like below,

```
 const contacts =  new mongoose.Schema({
  _id:{ type:String },
  taging:{ 
  type:String, 
  get: v=> v.split("|").join(","), 
  set:v=> v.split(",").join("|")
}
},{
  versionKey: false,
  toObject: { getters: true, setters: true },
  toJSON: { getters: true, setters: true },
  runSettersOnQuery: true,
})

const constactModel = mongoose.model('contacts', contacts, 'contacts');

module.exports = constactModel;
```

data on database looks like:

```
   { _id: "qwrvq2351", taging: "Sample| test| strange" },

   { _id: "qwrvqRR2351", taging: "Apple| Orange| cherry" }

   { _id: "XZCDAEAW", taging: "one| two| three" }
```

I want to fetch all list of contacts, but taging should be like this "Sample| test| strange" to "Sample, test, strange".

when i run this query, get and set method is not working,

`constactModel.find()`

Comment: all work's fine for me can you show me the schema model?

Comment: I have added the schema above 

 const contacts =  new mongoose.Schema({
  _id:{type:String},
  taging:{type:String, 
  get: v=> v.split("|").join(","), 
  set:v=> v.split(",").join("|")
}
},{
  versionKey: false,
  toObject: { getters: true, setters: true },
  toJSON: { getters: true, setters: true },
  runSettersOnQuery: true,
})

Answer (score 1):

```
import mongoose, { Schema } from "mongoose";

const contactsSchema =  new Schema({
    _id:{type:String},
    taging:{type:String, 
    get: v=> v.split("|").join(","), 
    set:v=> v.split(",").join("|")
  }
  },{
    versionKey: false,
    toObject: { getters: true, setters: true },
    toJSON: { getters: true, setters: true },
    runSettersOnQuery: true,
  });

const collectionName = "contact";

const contact = mongoose.model('contact',contactsSchema,collectionName);

export default contact;
```

Comment: Hi Hemant, i have used same in my schema, but still it doesn't work

Comment: you need output something like this right `[{
      _id: 'dfdddsfdsfhbs',
      taging: 'Sample, test, strange'
    },
    {
      _id: 'kgnhgnmjhg',
      taging: 'frgrd, dsfsdf, rhdhj',
    }
  ]`

Comment: yes Hemant, i need the same output

Comment: Actually i don't get it why it's not working for you .i'm using this function to create and find     `let contact = await Contact.create(req.body);` and
    `let findContact = await Contact.find();`